# Style each link (many) based on a media query

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries, stylesheet

I have many links on the page as part of a list.

I want to style each link with a different background-position based on a media query.

**What I've Got So Far**

```
a.firstLink
{
 @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px)
 {
   background-position:0px 0px;
 }
}
a.secondLink
{
 @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px)
 {
   background-position:0px -100px;
 }
}
```

This is fine, and works, but it means me having to do as many media queries as there are links, and there are a lot. Multiply this by the amount of media queries I'd like to do per link (3) and it's going to grow into some ugly CSS.

Comment: And why exactly don't you put the anchors inside the media query?

Comment: Explain how they could be used to solve this problem please belens, I'm not overly familiar with them.

Comment: Zoidberg posted my suggestion as an answer ;)

Answer (score 3):

How is this solution?

```
   @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {

    a.firstLink {
       background-position:0px 0px;
     }

    a.secondLink {
       background-position:0px -100px;
     }

    }
```

Does it work fine?

Second solution:

```
   @media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 599px),
   (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 767px),
   (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {

    a.firstLink {
       background-position:0px 0px;
     }

    a.secondLink {
       background-position:0px -100px;
     }

    }
```

Is this good?

Comment: That will work fine, but then I have the same issue of duplicate code. Less media queries, granted, but I'll have 3 long lists of links for each media query. +1.

Comment: But, dude. Media Quaries must be duplicated inherently. That's normal.

Comment: I'm not convinced this is the most efficient way. With regards to the edit, this would imply the style is the same across all 3 media queries, it's now. Thanks a lot for your answer anyway.